# The latest value does not seem to get updated. Only when I close and re-open the app, I can see the latest value displayed.

Tags: android, csv, ftp, real-time-updates

The basic functionality of the app is to get real time data from a .csv file present in an FTP server (Note: The .csv file on the server​ keeps updating simultaneously from another source.) and display the values on a graph.

I am able to successfully connect to the FTP server and parse the .csv file and display all the logged values onto the graph. But, the latest value does not seem to get updated on the graph. Only when I close and re-open the app, I can see the latest value displayed on graph.

I've tried the following code without success:

```
   /*
 * Connects to a remote FTP server
 */
void connectToFTP() {

    try {

        mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
        mFTPClient.connect(FTP_HOSTNAME, FTP_PORT);
        returnCode = mFTPClient.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(returnCode)) {
            throw new IOException("Could not connect");
        }
        boolean loggedIn = mFTPClient.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASSWORD);
        if (!loggedIn) {
            throw new IOException("Could not login");
        }
        System.out.println("Connected and Logged in");
        statusUpdate.setText("Connected to FTP Server");
        mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void beginListenForData() throws IOException {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character


    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    mmInputStream = mFTPClient.retrieveFileStream(fileName);

    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {
                try {
                    Log.i("Inside begindata ", "data " + count++);
                    int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                    if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if (b == delimiter) {
                                byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                readBufferPosition = 0;

                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        myLabel.setText(data);

                                        String s = data;
                                        String[] values = data.split(",");
                                        Log.i("Text ", "data " + values[3]);
                                        datalist.add(values[3]);
                                        power.setText(values[3]);



                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                            }
                        }
                        // dataPoints();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    stopWorker = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    workerThread.start();
}
```

Comment: store your parsed values in SQLite DB and refresh data using content providers.

Comment: I'm new to android and SQLite. Can you please show an example?

Answer (score 0):

Use Async task for download the data from the server and update the UI in the onPostExecute method.

start this Async task from "onCreate" method of Activity.

Comment: I'm new to android. Can you please show with an example?